# Why does url disappear from python scrapy?

Tags: python, url, scrapy

Why does url disappear from python scrapy?

```
disappear_url = 'https://disqus.com/embed/comments/?base=default&f=zdnet-1&t_i=5d1b4eb7-9581-4eaa-acb9-5fbc6c15bdb7&t_u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zdnet.com%2Fproduct%2Fsamsung-chg9-series-c49hg90dmn-qled-monitor-curved-49%2F&t_e=Samsung%2049%20inch%20QLED%20business%20monitor%20review%3A%20Multi-tasking%20single%20monitor%20setup&t_d=Samsung%2049%20inch%20QLED%20business%20monitor%20review%3A%20Multi-tasking%20single%20monitor%20setup&t_t=Samsung%2049%20inch%20QLED%20business%20monitor%20review%3A%20Multi-tasking%20single%20monitor%20setup&s_o=default#version=48537a333e429dcb726ce9cdcc57a44f'
```

I tried this.

```
scrapy shell disppear_url
```

response.url

```
https://disqus.com/embed/comments/?base=default&f=zdnet-1&t_i=5d1b4eb7-9581-4eaa-acb9-5fbc6c15bdb7&t_u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zdnet.com%2Fproduct%2Fsamsung-chg9-series-c49hg90dmn-qled-monitor-curved-49%2F&t_e=Samsung%2049%20inch%20QLED%20business%20monitor%20review%3A%20Multi-tasking%20single%20monitor%20setup&t_d=Samsung%2049%20inch%20QLED%20business%20monitor%20review%3A%20Multi-tasking%20single%20monitor%20setup&t_t=Samsung%2049%20inch%20QLED%20business%20monitor%20review%3A%20Multi-tasking%20single%20monitor%20setup&s_o=default
```

response.request.url

```
https://disqus.com/embed/comments/?base=default&f=zdnet-1&t_i=5d1b4eb7-9581-4eaa-acb9-5fbc6c15bdb7&t_u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zdnet.com%2Fproduct%2Fsamsung-chg9-series-c49hg90dmn-qled-monitor-curved-49%2F&t_e=Samsung%2049%20inch%20QLED%20business%20monitor%20review%3A%20Multi-tasking%20single%20monitor%20setup&t_d=Samsung%2049%20inch%20QLED%20business%20monitor%20review%3A%20Multi-tasking%20single%20monitor%20setup&t_t=Samsung%2049%20inch%20QLED%20business%20monitor%20review%3A%20Multi-tasking%20single%20monitor%20setup&s_o=default#version=48537a333e429dcb726ce9cdcc57a44f
```

help me.

Comment: What is your question ? what disappeared ?

Comment: # after disapperared

Comment: should have # up to the screen

Comment: Part after # is called as fragment identifieris and only used by the browser

Comment: Thank you awesome!!